# ¿Por qué mi hamburguer menu no se muestra en el 100% de la pantalla?

Tags: html, css

Tengo mi página mobile first con un hamburger menu, pero al momento de abrirlo no se muestra en el 100% de la pantalla, tengo puesta la propiedad para que ocupe el alto de `100%` pero al parecer no la aplica, intenté utilizar igualmente `100vh`, pero de la misma manera no ocupa todo el alto de la pantalla en dispositivos móviles.

**Código utilizado**

```js
mostrarNav = () => {
  document.getElementsByClassName('header__navigation__hamburguer')[0].classList.toggle('active');
};
```

```css
/* FONTS */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Pro:wght@200&family=Lora:wght@500;700&family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');

/* VARIABLES */


/* FUNCTIONS*/


/* GLOBAL RESETS */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  //border     : 1px solid palegreen;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  background-color: #181719;
  height: 100vh;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}


/* HEADING STYLES */

h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Crimson Pro', serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 200;
}

h2 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-size: 3.6rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

h3 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

h4 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

h5 {
  color: #A9A9A9;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 37.5rem;
  width: 90%;
}


/* HEADER */

.header {
  margin-bottom: 3.8rem;
  padding-top: 1.9rem;
}

.header__menu__container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}

.header__menu__container h1 {
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer {
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer span {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  height: 0.3rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  width: 3rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu {
  background-color: #181719;
  clip-path: circle(40px at calc(50% + (37.5rem / 2) - (40px / 2)) calc(0% + 1.9rem + (40px / 2)));
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer.active+.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu {
  clip-path: circle(100%);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__links {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-bottom: 0.6rem;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  padding-bottom: 0.6rem;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-width: 6;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 600ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1), stroke-dashoffset 600ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.line1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 60 207;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.line2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 60 60;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.line3 {
  stroke-dasharray: 60 207;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.active .line1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 90 207;
  stroke-dashoffset: -134;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.active .line2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 1 60;
  stroke-dashoffset: -30;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.active .line3 {
  stroke-dasharray: 90 207;
  stroke-dashoffset: -134;
  stroke-width: 6;
}


/* MAIN */

.main {
  padding-bottom: 6.1rem;
}

.main__information__details {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.main__information__details h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.main__information__details p {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  max-width: 25rem;
}

.main__information__details__button {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main__information__details__button a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.main__information__details__button a span {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
}

.main__information__product {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(13, 1fr);
}

.main__information__product__image {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.main__information__product__image img {
  width: 100%;
}

.main__information__product__box {
  margin-top: -20%;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background: #181719;
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 3/13;
  padding: 1.317rem 0 2.5rem 1.9rem;
}

.main__information__product__person {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1.824rem;
}

.main__information__product__person img {
  height: 3.6rem;
  width: 3.6rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 1.39rem;
}

.main__information__product__person__details h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0.585rem;
}

.main__information__product__person__details p {
  color: #828282;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.main__information__product h4 {
  max-width: 21rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__container container">
    <div class="header__menu__container">
      <h1>This Interior</h1>
      <div class="header__navigation">
        <div class="header__navigation__hamburguer " onclick="mostrarNav()">
          <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <path class="line line1" d="M 20,29.000046 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,29.000046 94.498839,28.817352 94.532987,66.711331 94.543142,77.980673 90.966081,81.670246 85.259173,81.668997 79.552261,81.667751 75.000211,74.999942 75.000211,74.999942 L 25.000021,25.000058"/>
            <path class="line line2" d="M 20,50 H 80"/>
            <path class="line line3" d="M 20,70.999954 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,70.999954 94.498839,71.182648 94.532987,33.288669 94.543142,22.019327 90.966081,18.329754 85.259173,18.331003 79.552261,18.332249 75.000211,25.000058 75.000211,25.000058 L 25.000021,74.999942"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <nav class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu">
          <ul class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__links">
            <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
              <a class="link-social" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
              <a class="link-social" href="#">Collection</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
              <a class="link-social" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
              <a class="link-social" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<main class="main">
  <div class="main__information container">
    <div class="main__information__details">
      <h2>Modern Interior</h2>
      <p>A full-Service residential & commercial interior design and staging company offering professional organizing & eco-services.</p>
      <div class="main__information__details__button">
        <a href="#">Read more <span class="material-icons">trending_flat</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main__information__product">
      <figure class="main__information__product__image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/700" alt="">
      </figure>
      <div class="main__information__product__box">
        <div class="main__information__product__person">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/36/36" alt="">
          <div class="main__information__product__person__details">
            <h3>Aliza Webber</h3>
            <p>Interior designer</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h4>Designed in 2020 by Aliza Webber</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no ocupa el 100% de la pantalla? Parece ocuparlo perfectamente. ¿Quieres que ocupe el 100% de la página (todo el scroll)?

Comment: Depende el dispositivo móvil, en iPhone se visualiza bien, pero en el caso de ser un Samsung Galaxy S9, se puede visualizar que no ocupa el 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existen una explicación para cada uno de los casos.

### Caso "alto igual a `100vh`":

La unidad `vh` hace referencia a la *"altura del viewport"*, que si llegara a existir scroll vertical, seria menor al alto total del documento.

- [Longitudes de porcentaje del viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/length#unidades_de_longitud_relativa)
- [Viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Viewport)

### Caso "alto igual al `100%`":

Cuando se indica que un elemento se posiciona de forma `absolute` y se indica que el alto es igual al `100%`, y no existe un ancestro con posición `absolute, relative o 'fixed`, se toma como *"contenedor"* el `viewport`.

- [The 'height' property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property)
- [Definition of "containing block"](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details)

Si se quiere el `100%` sea el equivalente al de un **elemento ancestro** específico, simplemente hay que indicar que dicho elemento se posiciona de forma `absolute, relative o 'fixed`. Así se consigue el **elemento descendiente** cubra al `100%` el **elemento ancestro**

Es decir, si indicamos que:

- El `body` tiene `position: relative;`
- El `header__navigation__hamburguer__menu` tiene  `position: absolute; height: 100%;`

Vamos a conseguir que el menú cubra por completo toda la página.

#### Demo:

```js
mostrarNav = () => {
  document.getElementsByClassName('header__navigation__hamburguer')[0].classList.toggle('active');
};
```

```css
/* FONTS */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Pro:wght@200&family=Lora:wght@500;700&family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');

/* VARIABLES */


/* FUNCTIONS*/


/* GLOBAL RESETS */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  //border     : 1px solid palegreen;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  background-color: #181719;
  position: relative; /* <------------- ACA ----------  */
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}


/* HEADING STYLES */

h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Crimson Pro', serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 200;
}

h2 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-size: 3.6rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

h3 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

h4 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

h5 {
  color: #A9A9A9;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 37.5rem;
  width: 90%;
}

/* HEADER */

.header {
  margin-bottom: 3.8rem;
  padding-top: 1.9rem;
}

.header__menu__container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}

.header__menu__container h1 {
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer {
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer span {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  height: 0.3rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  width: 3rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu {
  background-color: #181719;
  clip-path: circle(40px at calc(50% + (37.5rem / 2) - (40px / 2)) calc(0% + 1.9rem + (40px / 2)));
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer.active+.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu {
  clip-path: circle(100%);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__links {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-bottom: 0.6rem;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  padding-bottom: 0.6rem;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-width: 6;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 600ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1), stroke-dashoffset 600ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.line1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 60 207;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.line2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 60 60;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.line3 {
  stroke-dasharray: 60 207;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.active .line1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 90 207;
  stroke-dashoffset: -134;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.active .line2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 1 60;
  stroke-dashoffset: -30;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.active .line3 {
  stroke-dasharray: 90 207;
  stroke-dashoffset: -134;
  stroke-width: 6;
}


/* MAIN */

.main {
  padding-bottom: 6.1rem;
}

.main__information__details {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.main__information__details h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.main__information__details p {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  max-width: 25rem;
}

.main__information__details__button {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main__information__details__button a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.main__information__details__button a span {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
}

.main__information__product {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(13, 1fr);
}

.main__information__product__image {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.main__information__product__image img {
  width: 100%;
}

.main__information__product__box {
  margin-top: -20%;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background: #181719;
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 3/13;
  padding: 1.317rem 0 2.5rem 1.9rem;
}

.main__information__product__person {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1.824rem;
}

.main__information__product__person img {
  height: 3.6rem;
  width: 3.6rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 1.39rem;
}

.main__information__product__person__details h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0.585rem;
}

.main__information__product__person__details p {
  color: #828282;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.main__information__product h4 {
  max-width: 21rem;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 2.4rem;
}

footer h5 strong {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Interior Consultant</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="devchallenges.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header class="header">
    <div class="header__container container">
      <div class="header__menu__container">
        <h1>This Interior</h1>
        <div class="header__navigation">
          <div class="header__navigation__hamburguer " onclick="mostrarNav()">
            <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                                <path class="line line1"
                                      d="M 20,29.000046 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,29.000046 94.498839,28.817352 94.532987,66.711331 94.543142,77.980673 90.966081,81.670246 85.259173,81.668997 79.552261,81.667751 75.000211,74.999942 75.000211,74.999942 L 25.000021,25.000058"/>
                                <path class="line line2"
                                      d="M 20,50 H 80"/>
                                <path class="line line3"
                                      d="M 20,70.999954 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,70.999954 94.498839,71.182648 94.532987,33.288669 94.543142,22.019327 90.966081,18.329754 85.259173,18.331003 79.552261,18.332249 75.000211,25.000058 75.000211,25.000058 L 25.000021,74.999942"/>
                            </svg>
          </div>
          <nav class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu">
            <ul class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__links">
              <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
                <a class="link-social" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
                <a class="link-social" href="#">Collection</a>
              </li>
              <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
                <a class="link-social" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
                <a class="link-social" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="main__information container">
      <div class="main__information__details">
        <h2>Modern Interior</h2>
        <p>A full-Service residential & commercial interior design and staging company offering professional organizing & eco-services.</p>
        <div class="main__information__details__button">
          <a href="#">Read more <span class="material-icons">trending_flat</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main__information__product">
        <figure class="main__information__product__image">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/700" alt="">
        </figure>
        <div class="main__information__product__box">
          <div class="main__information__product__person">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/36/36" alt="">
            <div class="main__information__product__person__details">
              <h3>Aliza Webber</h3>
              <p>Interior designer</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h4>Designed in 2020 by Aliza Webber</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="container">
    <h5>created by <strong>soydavidpaucar</strong> - devChallenges.io</h5>
  </footer>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Lo malo de esta estrategia es al existir scroll, también vamos a tener que hacer scroll para llegar a las opciones del menú.

Si quisiéramos evitar tener que hacer scroll, entonces lo que podríamos hacer es que cuando se abre el menú, el `body` no tenga scroll.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
mostrarNav = () => {
  document.getElementsByClassName('header__navigation__hamburguer')[0].classList.toggle('active');
  /* Ocultamos el contenido que supera el alto del body */
  document.body.classList.toggle('hide-scroll');
};
```

```css
/* FONTS */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Pro:wght@200&family=Lora:wght@500;700&family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');

/* VARIABLES */


/* FUNCTIONS*/


/* GLOBAL RESETS */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  //border     : 1px solid palegreen;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  background-color: #181719;
}
body.hide-scroll { /* <------------- ACA ----------  */
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}


/* HEADING STYLES */

h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Crimson Pro', serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 200;
}

h2 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-size: 3.6rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

h3 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

h4 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

h5 {
  color: #A9A9A9;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 37.5rem;
  width: 90%;
}

/* HEADER */

.header {
  margin-bottom: 3.8rem;
  padding-top: 1.9rem;
}

.header__menu__container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}

.header__menu__container h1 {
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer {
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer span {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  height: 0.3rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  width: 3rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu {
  background-color: #181719;
  clip-path: circle(40px at calc(50% + (37.5rem / 2) - (40px / 2)) calc(0% + 1.9rem + (40px / 2)));
  height: 100vh; /* <------------- ACA ----------  */
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer.active+.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu {
  clip-path: circle(100%);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__links {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-bottom: 0.6rem;
}

.header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  padding-bottom: 0.6rem;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-width: 6;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 600ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1), stroke-dashoffset 600ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.line1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 60 207;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.line2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 60 60;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.line3 {
  stroke-dasharray: 60 207;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.active .line1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 90 207;
  stroke-dashoffset: -134;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.active .line2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 1 60;
  stroke-dashoffset: -30;
  stroke-width: 6;
}

.active .line3 {
  stroke-dasharray: 90 207;
  stroke-dashoffset: -134;
  stroke-width: 6;
}


/* MAIN */

.main {
  padding-bottom: 6.1rem;
}

.main__information__details {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.main__information__details h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.main__information__details p {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  max-width: 25rem;
}

.main__information__details__button {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main__information__details__button a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.main__information__details__button a span {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
}

.main__information__product {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(13, 1fr);
}

.main__information__product__image {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.main__information__product__image img {
  width: 100%;
}

.main__information__product__box {
  margin-top: -20%;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background: #181719;
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 3/13;
  padding: 1.317rem 0 2.5rem 1.9rem;
}

.main__information__product__person {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1.824rem;
}

.main__information__product__person img {
  height: 3.6rem;
  width: 3.6rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 1.39rem;
}

.main__information__product__person__details h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0.585rem;
}

.main__information__product__person__details p {
  color: #828282;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.main__information__product h4 {
  max-width: 21rem;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 2.4rem;
}

footer h5 strong {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Interior Consultant</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="devchallenges.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header class="header">
    <div class="header__container container">
      <div class="header__menu__container">
        <h1>This Interior</h1>
        <div class="header__navigation">
          <div class="header__navigation__hamburguer " onclick="mostrarNav()">
            <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                                <path class="line line1"
                                      d="M 20,29.000046 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,29.000046 94.498839,28.817352 94.532987,66.711331 94.543142,77.980673 90.966081,81.670246 85.259173,81.668997 79.552261,81.667751 75.000211,74.999942 75.000211,74.999942 L 25.000021,25.000058"/>
                                <path class="line line2"
                                      d="M 20,50 H 80"/>
                                <path class="line line3"
                                      d="M 20,70.999954 H 80.000231 C 80.000231,70.999954 94.498839,71.182648 94.532987,33.288669 94.543142,22.019327 90.966081,18.329754 85.259173,18.331003 79.552261,18.332249 75.000211,25.000058 75.000211,25.000058 L 25.000021,74.999942"/>
                            </svg>
          </div>
          <nav class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu">
            <ul class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__links">
              <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
                <a class="link-social" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
                <a class="link-social" href="#">Collection</a>
              </li>
              <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
                <a class="link-social" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="header__navigation__hamburguer__menu__link">
                <a class="link-social" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="main__information container">
      <div class="main__information__details">
        <h2>Modern Interior</h2>
        <p>A full-Service residential & commercial interior design and staging company offering professional organizing & eco-services.</p>
        <div class="main__information__details__button">
          <a href="#">Read more <span class="material-icons">trending_flat</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main__information__product">
        <figure class="main__information__product__image">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/700" alt="">
        </figure>
        <div class="main__information__product__box">
          <div class="main__information__product__person">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/36/36" alt="">
            <div class="main__information__product__person__details">
              <h3>Aliza Webber</h3>
              <p>Interior designer</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h4>Designed in 2020 by Aliza Webber</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="container">
    <h5>created by <strong>soydavidpaucar</strong> - devChallenges.io</h5>
  </footer>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si, otra opción es poner `fixed` al menú, modificar el markup para que el botón no quede por detrás del menú... pero se van a ver las "barras" de scroll (_aunque en móvil no molesten_)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu solución, muy acertada.